# How do I implement URL architecture like below on a wordpress website

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, custom-post-type, categories, permalinks

I need to implement URL architecture like below:

At this home url I am giving option to choose a city among total 32 cities available -

```
http://servicecenter.com/
```

Then user should redirect according choosed city like follows -

```
http://servicecenter.com/Surat/
http://servicecenter.com/Ajmer/
http://servicecenter.com/New-Delhi/
```

City specific URL should show list of available Products Type, Services Type and Bulletins Type specific to that city with count. And on clicking on a Type should redirect to URL like -

```
http://servicecenter.com/Surat/food/
http://servicecenter.com/Surat/ticket-booking/
http://servicecenter.com/Surat/Medical/
```

This city and type specific URL page should have list of posts available. And clicking on a post should redirect to URL like -

```
http://servicecenter.com/Surat/food/Chandan-Sweet-House/
```

As I know I can do using this categories, tags, and custom post types but I am not able to use permalinks in a way that I need.

Answer (score 0):

If you select category in the permalink it should work e.g. in WordPress settings for Permalink, select custom

```
/%category%/%postname%/
```

Then create categories for each city and subcategories as needed e.g. food, driving etc

When you create the post, select the subcategory and the full category/subcategory should be linked in the URL

Comment: I need same subcategories in each city. Then What should I do! If I will make there 30 same subcategories in 32 cities then there will be total 992 categories, it's not looking a good way to do.